# Do Acupressure Wristbands help with nausea?

Tags: alternative-medicine

I recently became aware of [Travel Wristbands](http://www.travelband.com/about-travelband.htm).

> TRAVELBAND provides effective control of motion sickness, travel sickness, morning sickness and all forms of nausea.

I can't find any serious studies that show that they work, or that they don't, or any reasonable explanation of the science behind them (if any?).

Have they been shown to work? How do they

Comment: I found this poor study (which "approached" statistical significance.) http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/12906958

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These bands work according to the principles of [Accupressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acupressure), which is derived from Accupuncture. For the alleged mechanism you can look up any source on those techniques, it is generally based on the concept of meridians and balancing ying, yang and qi. But I don't know of any explanation for these effects that I would call *scientific*.

I found a study called "[Efficacy of Acupressure and Acustimulation Bands for the Prevention of Motion Sickness](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/asma/asem/2004/00000075/00000003/art00006?crawler=true)" which investigated two similar products: Acuband and ReliefBand.

The study used 77 subjects in 5 categories. They concluded

> Neither band nor placebo prevented the development of motion sickness,
>   regardless of whether the bands were used correctly or incorrectly.

The study contains a rather uncritical description of accupressure, and the sample size is rather low, so I would not consider it very reliable.